# C# Rijndael encryption puts extra bytes in front of the decrypted files

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt image files using Rijndael encryption and I must be doing something wrong because the decrypted files are coming out with extra data at the front of the file any maybe a little extra at the end. I'm fairly new to this encryption algorithm so I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something simple.

**Examples using text files**

Input file

```
"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy yellow dog"
```

Output file when I try to put a generated IV at the front of the file(\0=null)

```
"ÚñjÐæƒÊW®ï¡_Ü&ßthe\0 quick brown fox jumped over the lazy yellow dog"
```

Output file when I try to put an IV that is equal to my Key at front

```
"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0the\0\0\0\0\0\0 quick brown fox jumped over the lazy yellow dog"
```

Output file when I use an IV that is equal to my Key and put nothing at  front of file

```
"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0the\0\0\0\0\0\0 quick brown fox jumped over the lazy yellow dog"
```

**CODE**

```csh
private RijndaelManaged GetCipher(byte[] key, bool forEncrypt)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;

    rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.Key = key;

   /* if (forEncrypt)
        rijndaelCipher.GenerateIV();
    else
    rijndaelCipher.IV = new byte[16];*/
    rijndaelCipher.IV = _imageKey;

    return rijndaelCipher;
}

public void DecryptStamp(Stamp stampToDecrypt, string decrpytedStampFilePath)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block;
    int numberRead;
    ICryptoTransform transform;

    if (!File.Exists(stampToDecrypt.Path))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampToDecrypt.Path + " does not exist");

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, false);
    block = new byte[16];

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampToDecrypt.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(decrpytedStampFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        //inputStream.Read(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, rijndaelCipher.IV.Length);
        transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor();                     
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numberRead.ToString());
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public Stamp EncryptStampToStampFolder(string stampFileToEncrpyt)
{
    Configuration config;
    Stamp stampToEncrypt;
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    string encryptedFilePath;

    if (!File.Exists(stampFileToEncrpyt))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampFileToEncrpyt + " does not exist");

    config = Configuration.GetProgramInstance();
    encryptedFilePath = Path.Combine(config.StampFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt) + ".stmp");

    stampToEncrypt = new Stamp(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt), encryptedFilePath);

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, true);
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block = new byte[16];
    int numberRead;

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampFileToEncrpyt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(encryptedFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        //outputStream.Write(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, 16);
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, block.Length);

        while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }

    return stampToEncrypt;
}

public struct Stamp
{
    public string Name,
        Path;

    public Stamp(string StampName, string StampPath)
    {
        Name = StampName;
        Path = StampPath;
    }
}
```

**CODE post fix**

```csh
private RijndaelManaged GetCipher(byte[] key, bool forEncrypt)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;

    rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.Key = key;

    if (forEncrypt)
        rijndaelCipher.GenerateIV();
    else
        rijndaelCipher.IV = new byte[16];
    //rijndaelCipher.IV = _imageKey;

    return rijndaelCipher;
}

public void DecryptStamp(Stamp stampToDecrypt, string decrpytedStampFilePath)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block;
    int numberRead;
    ICryptoTransform transform;

    if (!File.Exists(stampToDecrypt.Path))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampToDecrypt.Path + " does not exist");

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, false);
    block = new byte[16];

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampToDecrypt.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(decrpytedStampFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        inputStream.Read(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, rijndaelCipher.IV.Length);
        transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor();                     
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {                
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public Stamp EncryptStampToStampFolder(string stampFileToEncrpyt)
{
    Configuration config;
    Stamp stampToEncrypt;
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    string encryptedFilePath;

    if (!File.Exists(stampFileToEncrpyt))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampFileToEncrpyt + " does not exist");

    config = Configuration.GetProgramInstance();
    encryptedFilePath = Path.Combine(config.StampFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt) + ".stmp");

    stampToEncrypt = new Stamp(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt), encryptedFilePath);

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, true);
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block = new byte[16];
    int numberRead;

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampFileToEncrpyt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(encryptedFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        outputStream.Write(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, 16);
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        //encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, block.Length); this line was the problem in the orginal code

        while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }

    return stampToEncrypt;
}

public struct Stamp
{
    public string Name,
        Path;

    public Stamp(string StampName, string StampPath)
    {
        Name = StampName;
        Path = StampPath;
    }
}
```

**New Code's output**

"7p¶¼oò¾½G€¢9±hfox\0\0 jumped over the lazy yellow dog"

Comment: I may be overlooking something, but I cannot see in your EncryptStampToStampFolder method where you are giving any values to block[] before writing it.  I see you commented out your line where you write rijndaelCipher.IV, so I assume you wanted to assign rijndaelCipher.IV to block before writing it.  Be aware that if you get the IV wrong in CBC mode, only the first block will be corrupted on decrypt and everything else will be fine.  Maybe that is the issue here?

Comment: `while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }`
is where I fill block[] from the inputstream and send it to the encryptStream.

IV is set in GetCipher and that comment out write you saw was for when i want to put the IV at the start of the file

Comment: OK, see the line we are talking about that you commented out?  Look 2 lines below that.  You are writing 16 bytes from block[] before reading anything into it.

Comment: Yep I see it now. I can't believe I kept missing that. the code works except when I use uncomment the generateIV in getCipher and write the IV to beginning of the encrypted file the decrpyted file is junk again

Ill edit to show what I mean

Comment: "an IV that is equal to my Key"... you probably should read about what the IV is supposed to be and the requirements for it. The safest thing to do as a layman is to generate a cryptographically strong IV and send it with the ciphertext.

Comment: Yes that was just to quickly create a stable repeatable test environment. I'm trying to get RijndaelManaged.generateIV to work now and then I put it at the front of the encrypted file

Comment: I have a feeling your cryptostream is writing to the file starting at position 0 and is therefore overwriting your IV.  Not sure though...

Comment: Can you write the IV to file, close the file stream, then reopen it in Append mode to write the ciphertext?  I admit I am just making an educated guess at this point though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was three fold. 
1)Extra data being written during encryption
2)The IV at the beginning of the file was being overwritten
3)The IV was not being read properly on decryption

**CODE Fixed**

```csh
private RijndaelManaged GetCipher(byte[] key, bool forEncrypt)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;

    rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.Key = key;

    if (forEncrypt)
        rijndaelCipher.GenerateIV();
    else
        rijndaelCipher.IV = new byte[16];
    //rijndaelCipher.IV = _imageKey;

    return rijndaelCipher;
}

public void DecryptStamp(Stamp stampToDecrypt, string decrpytedStampFilePath)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block;
    int numberRead;
    ICryptoTransform transform;

    if (!File.Exists(stampToDecrypt.Path))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampToDecrypt.Path + " does not exist");

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, false);
    block = new byte[16];

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampToDecrypt.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(decrpytedStampFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        //This line was wrong because rijndaelCipher.IV never filled
        //inputStream.Read(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, rijndaelCipher.IV.Length); 

        inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
        rijndaelCipher.IV = block;
        block = new byte[16];
        transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor();                     
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        while ((numberRead = inputStream.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {                
            encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public Stamp EncryptStampToStampFolder(string stampFileToEncrpyt)
{
    Configuration config;
    Stamp stampToEncrypt;
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher;
    string encryptedFilePath;

    if (!File.Exists(stampFileToEncrpyt))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(stampFileToEncrpyt + " does not exist");

    config = Configuration.GetProgramInstance();
    encryptedFilePath = Path.Combine(config.StampFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt) + ".stmp");

    stampToEncrypt = new Stamp(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stampFileToEncrpyt), encryptedFilePath);

    rijndaelCipher = this.GetCipher(_imageKey, true);
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

    FileStream inputStream = null;
    FileStream outputStream = null;
    CryptoStream encryptSteam = null;
    byte[] block = new byte[16];
    int numberRead;

    try
    {
        inputStream = File.Open(stampFileToEncrpyt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = File.Open(encryptedFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        outputStream.Write(rijndaelCipher.IV, 0, IV.Length);
        //This had to be changed so that the IV was not overwitten
        //encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write); 
        encryptSteam = new CryptoStream(inputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        //this line was a problem in the orginal code that caused extra data to be added to the encrypted file
        //encryptSteam.Write(block, 0, block.Length); 

        while ((numberRead = encryptSteam.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(block, 0, numberRead);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher.Clear();
        rijndaelCipher.Dispose();
        if (encryptSteam != null)
            encryptSteam.Dispose();
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.Dispose();
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.Dispose();
    }

    return stampToEncrypt;
}

public struct Stamp
{
    public string Name,
        Path;

    public Stamp(string StampName, string StampPath)
    {
        Name = StampName;
        Path = StampPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to decrypt:

```
    private RijndaelManaged GetAesProvider(Stream stm, bool isEncryption)
    {
        byte[] finalKey = GetFinalKey();
        // GetIV either gets salt on encryption and writes it into stm
        // or reads it from stm if it's decryption
        byte[] iv = GetIV(stm, isEncryption);
        RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.BlockSize = kAesBlockSizeInBytes * 8;
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Key = finalKey;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        return aes;
    }

    public override Stream GetDecryptionStream(Stream source)
    {
        if (source.Length <= kIVSize)
        {
            return new EmptyStream();
        }
        RijndaelManaged aes = GetAesProvider(source, false);
        ICryptoTransform xform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        return new CryptoStream(source, xform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    }
```

Comment: using CreateDecryptor(Key, IV) and CryptoStreamMode.Read had the same effect